# Logically equivalent formulas and contradiction

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$\lnot A \Rightarrow A$ , is a contradiction.

But $\lnot A \Rightarrow A$  is logically equivalent to $A\lor A$. Does it mean that $A\lor A$ always give contradiction?

Comment: No, $\neg A\implies A$ is _not_ a contradiction.

Comment: ¬(A ---> A) is contradiction. Is this right? @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: A(and)¬A must be contradiction which is equivalent to ¬(A ---> A) . Am I right? @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: Yes, $\neg(A\implies A)$ is a contradiction. But it's not equivalent to $A\lor  A$ as you said it was...

Comment: Have you learned about "truth tables"?

Comment: Yes but see comment in one of answer. And I am not using truth table but trying to work with axiom of Deductions only with definition A∧B in terms of ⇒ @DavidC.Ullrich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mistaking $\neg (A \Rightarrow A)$ with $(\neg A) \Rightarrow A$:

- $\neg (A \Rightarrow A)$ is false no matter whether $A$ is true or false.
- $(\neg A) \Rightarrow A$ is logically equivalent to $A \vee A$, which is itself logically equivalent to $A$. Thus it is true when $A$ is true and false when $A$ is false.

They are not the same thing. Unless you have some kind of binding convention, the expression $\neg A \Rightarrow A$ is ambiguous, and you should insert parentheses.

Comment: Okay this I got. So A--->B(and)C is not equivalent to (A-->B)(and)(A--->C) because otherwise I get (¬A)⇒A

Comment: Actually $A \Rightarrow (B \wedge C)$ is logically equivalent to $(A \Rightarrow B) \wedge (A \Rightarrow C)$.

Comment: @Sushil: $A\implies(\lnot B\land B)$ is not a contradiction, it is the statement that assuming $A$ would imply a contradiction. As such, it is equivalent to $\lnot A$.

Comment: Yes got it  A---> (¬B∧B) equivalent to  ¬A. Thanks @celtschk

Comment: [(A⇒B) V (A⇒C)] ⇒ [¬(A⇒B) ⇒ (A⇒C)] ⇒[(A∧¬B) ⇒ (A⇒C)].   Is (A⇒B) V (A⇒C)] equivalent to A⇒(B V C).   How can I prove it from [(A∧¬B) ⇒ (A⇒C)]?   @CliveNewstead

Comment: @Sushil: I'm not an on-call service, please stop pinging me! I was happy to answer your question, but I have lots of other things I have to do at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

A proof by contradiction is a proof in which you make an hypothesis $\neg A$ and get $A$ as a consequence. As you said it means that $\neg A \Rightarrow A$ which is equivalent to $A$.

Finally it is a proof as you have either $A$ or $\neg A$ and in fact the only possible case is $A$.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add what @clive answered.

The statement 
  ¬
  A
  ⇒
  A
 which reduces to A is more formally called a Contingency